# Handle NullReferenceException when processing a list of elements

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

In the current scenario I’m filling the list but when I go to the `ItemsinList`, many of the value will be `null` and as you can see I tried to control the string null value but it gives me the error.  As I fill the data source on the list line of the code it gives the error of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I’d already tried `IsNullOrEmpty`, `Equals(string.Empty)` and given it default value as `null` but its still breaks. My question is how can I handle the null values?

```
var items = CommonList.ItemList();
items.Insert(0,new DataModel.SKU(){SKUID = 0,SKUName = "abc" });
var itemsinlist = from obj in items
                  select new { obj.SKUID, obj.SKUName,string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.SKUCode), 
                      obj.SalePrice, obj.PurchasePrice, obj.CostPrice, 
                      // if is null the code breaks 
                      obj.BaseUnit.UnitName, obj.SKUGroup.SKUGroupName,
                      obj.SKUBrand.SKUBrandName, obj.Unit_Weight };

var objlist = itemsinlist as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
// can not add list if some value is null althought the db value can be null
this.cmbSKU.ValueMember = "SKUID";
this.cmbSKU.DisplayMember = "SKUName";
this.cmbSKU.DataSource = itemsinlist.ToList();
```

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` returns you a boolean value, so you have to check this value and decide what you want to do. You could write an empty string if the value is null, for example, `(obj.SKUCode == null)? String.Empty:obj.SKUCode` - if the SKUCode is null then it will return the empty string, otherwise SKUCode

Comment: not working same error as with null and empty string http://prntscr.com/9cv0b0

Comment: Error is :Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Comment: `SKUCode = (obj.SKUCode == null)? String.Empty:obj.SKUCode` it should work.

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? when you initialize the `itemsinList` or later?

Comment: in that case it does i was thinking some thing that i don't have to give it  explicit name

Comment: '                    this.cmbSKU.DataSource = itemsinlist.ToList();
'

Comment: check the anwer I've posted and let me know whether it solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have null values in the properties, it's not so bad. Let's consider this example:

```
var items = from obj in "Hello".ToCharArray()
            select new
            {
                First = (string)null
            };    
var listTemp = items.ToList();
```

When you call the `ToList` method it's totally fine.

Probably, the exception comes from the `null` element in the list, which you get from the `CommonList.ItemList()` method. I extend the previous example and add the `null` element into the list:

```
var listTemp = items.ToList();
listTemp.Add(null);

var itemsProcessed = from item in listTemp
                     select new
                     {
                         item.First 
                     };    
var list = itemsProcessed.ToList();
```

In this case the `NullReferenceException` will be thrown, because when we create the new element and try to get the `First` property we don't have a real element.

This issue can be easily solved if you **add the `where` clause** in the query:

```
var itemsProcessed = from item in listTemp
                     where item != null
                     select new
                     {
                         item.First 
                     };
```

Comment: Thanks mate it was helpful